# Sql Server Management Studio Express (2005 or 2008) - Save Password Doesn't work

Tags: ssms

I always click "Remember Password" when connecting to a database server.

Sometimes when I come back into SSMS, it has it remembered, sometimes not. More often it does not. I regularly connect to about 4 different servers, it's fairly random when it works for which servers.

How can I get this to work all the time?

Comment: I have this problem too, and not just with the Express versions.  Wrote it off as a "ghost in the machine" issue a while back.  Definitely wouldn't mind seeing a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup this is a known bug in SSMS - I believe all versions, [reported here on connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124842/remember-password-option-is-not-remembered-in-registered-server-properties). I have experienced it in the past, yet had machines that never had any problems.

I would love to say I have a solution for it, but unfortunately the solution for me was to allow windows authentication for connecting instead.

My recommendation is to post on the bug report and if enough people do it Microsoft will either fix it or provide information about it. Yes, they do pay attention to connect bug reports when they get 'popular'.

Comment: I'm really immpressed that MS let this persist from 2005 through 2008... and I'm guessing it'll be in 2010 SSMS as well

Comment: SSMS is kinda like a bastard child of the Visual Studio team + SQL team. And look at the duplication between the current VS and SSMS. Fact is, tooling for DBAs is not a priority from MS.

Comment: Do you think I should accept this answer or delete the question?

Comment: @eddiegroves the 2012 version of SSMS has "powered by visual studio" on the splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this link](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/775/save-frequently-used-connections-in-sql-server-management-studio) on the [connect link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124842/remember-password-option-is-not-remembered-in-registered-server-properties) provided by eddiegroves.

It is a tutorial that shows you how to create a new server registration. I've added one, restarted SSMS a couple times and it seems my password is still there...

Comment: Over 10 days and it is still working. Seems the perfect workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue in 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.  Haven't found a fix, but here's a workaround (sort of):  Assuming that you've successfully logged in to a given server previously...  When you open the "Connect to Database Engine" dialog, press the down arrow followed by the up arrow on your keyboard, and SSMS magically "remembers" the forgotten password!  Not a fix, but certainly easier that typing out a password.